# How to Check if an Array Contains a Value in brightscript Efficiently?

Tags: arrays, roku, brightscript

Given an roArray:

```
found = CreateObject("roArray", 0, true)
found.push("a")
found.push("b")
found.push("c")
```

What is the best way to check if value `s = "s"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use roArray - use roAssociativeArray instead:

```
found = {a: 1, b: 1}
found["c"] = true
if found.doesExist("s") then ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for something like this:

```
someArr.contains("s")
```

There is no such thing, you have to implement it yourself:

```
function contains(arr as Object, value as String) as Boolean
    for each entry in arr
        if entry = value
            return true
        end if
    end for
    return false
end function
```

Currently there are no more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: Can you please join to this chat? - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/125578/brightscript?tab=general